# EntityFramework - Load IDs to levels down without loading other columns

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have 3 entities: Banners, Packs and Files.

One Banner has many packs and one pack has many files.

I need to get all the files ids for all banners. I tried the following:

```
  IList<BannerModel> banners = context.Banners
    .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
    .Take(count)       
    .Select(x => 
      new BannerModel {
        Images = x.Packs.SelectMany(p => p.Files.Select(f => f.Id)).ToList()
      }).ToList();
```

However, I am getting an error on the Files id selecting:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
>   ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. 
>   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call)    at ...

Any idea of what might be wrong?

**NOTE:** I have Lazy Loading disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var allFileIDs = context.Banners.SelectMany(b => 
                           b.Packs.SelectMany(p => p.Files.Select(f => f.ID)))
                        .ToList();
```

Resulting SQL will look like:

```
SELECT [t2].[ID]
FROM [Banners] AS [t0], [Packs] AS [t1], [Files] AS [t2]
WHERE ([t1].[BannerID] = [t0].[ID]) AND ([t2].[PackID] = [t1].[ID])
```

No lazy-loading, single query.

---

Misunderstood your question about getting all file ids. If you need to project each banner to BannerModel:

```
context.Banners.Select(b => new BannerModel {
          Images = b.Packs.SelectMany(p => p.Files.Select(f => f.ID))
        }).ToList();
```

You see exception, because you have `ToList()` in expression, which cannot be converted into SQL. Change `BannerModel.Images` to be of type `IEnumerable<int>` instead of `List<int>`, and remove `ToList()` call from select statement.

---

One more option if you don't want to change type of `BannerModel.Images`:

```
context.Banners.Select(b => b.Packs.SelectMany(p => p.Files.Select(f => f.ID)))
               .ToList() // brings next projection into memory
               .Select(ids => new BannerModel { Images = ids.ToList() })
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't that need a Distinct()?

Comment: Why does it need Distinct? I know for sure that the Files Ids are all different ... And isn't possible to do the projection I did so I can define the ImageIds inside another query?

Comment: @Shapper agree again :) Removed useless Distinct(). If you were selecting something that is not PK, the Distinct() will be needed. In your case there is no need in it

Comment: I updated my code to show what I am looking for. Your suggestion works but I was looking to integrate it in a query as I just posted. However, I am getting the error I describe. Can't this be done?

Comment: Your suggestion does not work. That was what I did because it seemed logic but I got the error: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32] ToList[Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.DefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call) at ...

Comment: @Shapper if you will change `BannerModel.ImagesIds` to `IEnumerable<int>` and remove `ToList()` from  inner part of query, then query will work